# Evans proof of variational principal for the principal eigenvalue

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am self-studying Evans PDE book, this is theorem 2 on page 356, variational principle for the principle eigenvalue. In the book, given that $\{w_k\}$ eigenfunctions of a symmetric elliptic operator $L$,they also form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(U)$. If $\{\lambda_k\}$ are the eigenvalues of $L$, the book claims that $\{\frac{w_k}{\lambda_k^{1/2}}\}$ forms an orthonormal basis of $H^1_0(U)$ with respect to the inner product $B[,]$. Now my question is this: how do we know that $B[,]$ as an inner product turns $H^1_0(U)$ into a Hilbert space, and is this Hilbert space the same as the one using the standard inner product on $H^1_0(U)$.

I know there are a few questions on the site about this proof already, but I haven't found my question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the norm $$\| u\| := \|\nabla u \|_{L^2(U)}=\bigg ( \int_U \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx \bigg )^{1/2}   $$ on $H^1_0(U)$ (which is equivalent to the usual norm on $H^1_0(U)$ by the Poincaré inequality) and let $$ \| u \|':= (B[u,u])^{1/2}.$$ Then $\|\cdot \|$ and $\|\cdot \|'$ are equivalent norms on $H^1_0(U)$.

Indeed, Evans assumes $a^{ij}$ are bounded so for all $u,v\in H^1_0(U)$, $$B[u,u] = \sum_{i,j}\int_U a^{ij}u_{x_i}u_{x_j}\,dx\leqslant C\sum_{i,j}\int_U \vert u_{x_i}\vert \cdot \vert u_{x_j}\vert\,dx \leqslant C \| \nabla u \|_{L^2(U)}^2 $$ Moreover, by ellipticity, $$\sum_{i,j}\int_U a^{ij}u_{x_i}u_{x_j}\,dx \geqslant \theta \| \nabla u \|^2_{L^2(U)} . $$

This immediately implies that $(H^1_0(U), \| \cdot \|')$ is a Banach space with the same topology as $H^1_0(U)$ (with the usual norm). But then define $(u,v)':= B[u,v]$. One can verify that $(H^1_0(U), ( \cdot,\cdot ) ')$ is an inner product space and from the definition of $\| \cdot \|'$, the inner product $( \cdot,\cdot ) '$ induces the norm $\| \cdot \|'$. Then $(H^1_0(U), ( \cdot,\cdot ) ')$ is a Hilbert space since $\| \cdot\|'$ is complete on $H^1_0(U)$.

Comment: Can you explain why the bilinear form is $\sum \int_U a^{ij} u_{x_i} u_{x_j}$? In the theorem statement, $Lu =  -\sum (a_{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j}$, if we write out $(a_{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j}$, don't we need to use the product rule for derivative?

Comment: It is true that to write out $(a^{ij} u_{x_i})_{x_j}$ you would have to use the product rule but this is not how to obtain the bilinear form. It is obtained by multiplying $Lu$ be a test function $v$ then integrating by parts. I recommend looking at 6.1.2 in Evans